# enumerate process and get its associate windows title

Tags: visual-c++

I would like to enumerate process and get its associate windows title
how to do it

Comment: BTW You might want to accept some of your answers; it will dramatically increase the number of people who want to answer your questions.  22% is far too low.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate all windows using the `EnumWindows` function.  There's a good discussion of this at the MSDN: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183009